# Replace part of attr if not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im getting the id of next td element like this:

```
var controlID = nextTD.children().attr('id');
```

and it returns this:

```
controlID = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AntifibrinolyticsPanel_i0_i0_UIAntifibEpUsePanel"
```

Im trying to replace the string "Panel" at the end with empty string to just remove it.

I have tried with no luck:

```
nextTD.children().attr('id').replace("Panel","");
controlID.replace("Panel","");
```

Comment: Replace returns updated value and does not updates itself. Try `str = str.replace("Panel","");`

Comment: thank you for the fast response.  So something like this: var newID = controlID.replace("Panel","");

Comment: Are you wanting to change the element ID or just modify  the string?

Comment: I want to change the ID to look like this: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AntifibrinolyticsPanel_i0_i0_UIAntifibEpUse" instead of this ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AntifibrinolyticsPanel_i0_i0_UIAntifibEpUsePanel" that has the "Panel" in it

Comment: then you need to set the attribute. `attr()` is both `getter` and `setter` depending on whether a value argument is supplied or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove your last substring which is "Panel":

The **indexOf()** method with two parameters indicates that the first parameter is the parameter which tells what to search and the second tells at what index to start the search.

```
var controlID = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AntifibrinolyticsPanel_i0_i0_UIAntifibEpUsePanel";


var newindex=controlID.indexOf("Panel", controlID.indexOf("Panel") + 1);
var newstring= controlID.substr(0,newindex);
alert(newstring);
```

Comment: Thank you all for you help on this.  Thanks eugen sunic